# How to make a .svc file write to asp.net Trace.axd

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, .net-3.5, trace

I am trying to figure out how to make a 3.5 WCF service thats hosted under IIS write to the asp.net trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you would add this to the web.config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
          <listeners>
              <add name="AspTraceListener"
                   type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener" />
          </listeners>
      </source>
   </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```