# Trace messages not appearing in trace.axd

Tags: c#, asp.net, trace

I'm trying to write messages to the trace.axd file from a wcf service, however my trace messages are not ariving at all.

The code that I use to write the messages is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write("Value updated to: " + value.ToString());
```

In the web config file I have tracing enabled:

```
<trace enabled="true" requestLimit="15" pageOutput="false" localOnly="false"/>
```

However when I look at the trace.axd file, my messages are not available. I've even stepped through the code and I know its hitting the Trace.Write value.

The only thing that I can think of that is causing this is because the method has IgnoreDataMember above it.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a .svc file write to asp.net Trace.axd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341618/how-to-make-a-svc-file-write-to-asp-net-trace-axd).

Comment: That answer doens't work at all.

Answer (score 10):

When I see attribute `pageOutput` it clearly means that you are trying to configure **ASP .NET Trace** which only works for Web Applications. The `Trace.axd` is a web page generated by ASP .NET Trace.

The .NET framework itself has **.NET Trace** which works for all kinds of applications or projects (Web or Windows Applications, or your Class Library projects).
`System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write` is a function defined by .NET Trace.
By default, .NET Trace output is the output window inside Visual Studio. If you want to forward this output to the `Trace.axd` page, you need the configuration entry as suggested by Mathew Paxinos in his answer below:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
        <listeners>
            <add name="WebPageTraceListener"
                 type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

[Source MSDN Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/b0ectfxd(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#to-add-a-webpagetracelistener-for-your-application-through-configuration) 
*(verified on September 23rd, 2019)*

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing to System.Diagnostics.Trace, you will need to add the following to your web.config to have it write the output to the page / trace.axd:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
        <listeners>
            <add name="WebPageTraceListener"
                 type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

With thanks to:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

This is particularly useful when writing to trace from business logic layers or other objects outside the scope of the web project.